# I am trying to view a list of objects displayed per user but none are visible SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax, sqlplus

I was told to run this code to view a list of objects displayed

```
SELECT OWNER,OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = ‘sam';
```

When I run it I get this error

```
ORA-00904: "OWNER": invalid identifier
```

However, I am able to run this and it works

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE ‘BIN%’;
```

My aim is to see the list of objects that each role is allocated. I am using Oracles SQL Plus 18G

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, purge recyclebin to avoid `BIN%` objects (deleted ones).

```
SQL> purge recyclebin;

Recyclebin purged.
```

Now, query: if you select from `user_objects`, there's no `OWNER` column there. There is in `all_objects`, and then it makes sense to restrict the result because in my XE database such a query returns ~7.300 objects:

```
    SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type
      2  from all_objects
      3  order by owner, object_name;

    OWNER      OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE
    ---------- -------------------- --------------------
    PUBLIC     DUAL                 SYNONYM
    PUBLIC     MAP_OBJECT           SYNONYM
    PUBLIC     SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP SYNONYM
    PUBLIC     TABLE_PRIVILEGE_MAP  SYNONYM
    SYS        DUAL                 TABLE
    SYS        ORA$BASE             EDITION
    SYS        SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP TABLE
    SYS        TAB$                 TABLE
    SYS        TABLE_PRIVILEGE_MAP  TABLE
    <snip>
    XDB        XMLINDEX             INDEXTYPE
    XDB        XMLINDEXINSFUNC      FUNCTION
    XDB        XMLINDEXLOADFUNC     FUNCTION
    XDB        XMLINDEX_NOOP        OPERATOR

    7323 rows selected.
```

By default, unless you use double quotes when creating users/objects, Oracle "stores" everything in uppercase. So, `'sam'` doesn't exist in your database, but `'SAM'` does. So:

```
SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type
  2  from all_objects
  3  where owner = 'SAM'                --> uppercase in single quotes
  4  order by owner, object_name;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

I don't have user `SAM` so nothing has been returned, but should be in your database. If not, the answer is simple: user `SAM` doesn't have any objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper quotes but overall the table name is ALL_OBJECTS

USER_OBJECTS  is view for actual user and have not owner column

```
    SELECT OWNER,OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE 
    FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
    WHERE OWNER = 'sam'
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4378.htm#i1634422

Comment: For the top one, I got the error of 'ORA-00904: "sam": invalid identifier'. For the bottom one, I got the same error as before 'ORA-00904: "OWNER": invalid identifier'

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error, 'ORA-00904: "sam": invalid identifier'